# Databricks - an automated way to run cells several times by getting each time another input

Tags: python, automation, databricks

I need to run several cells in Databricks for each file I have. The input is an imagepath and for that imagepath there are like 40 cells that take 10 mins to run all of them. I have to run the code for 50 imagepaths. How can I automate this in Databricks in python? Is this even possible?

It is like this: get file and then run everything from below.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [dbutils notebook API](https://docs.databricks.com/notebooks/notebook-workflows.html#api) that allows you to run a notebook and pass widget parameters to it. It can be run in a loop like this:

```
imagepaths = [...]
for ip in imagepaths:
   dbutils.notebook.run("notebook", 0, {"imagepath": ip })
```

Note that it will run them sequentially. It would be nice to run the computation in parallel, but I'm not aware of a way to orchestrate it as Databricks job. You probably would need to do it externally with something like [ADF](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-for-each-activity) or [Airflow](https://www.astronomer.io/guides/dynamic-tasks/).